# Importing JSON File Data into R as Data Frame for NLP

Tags: json, r, parsing

I'm trying to import data from a JSON file into R in order to experiment with natural language processing. The data was parsed and extracted from a blog written in markdown. The problem is that the import in R is imported as lists and a funny format, and I can't figure out how to get it into a data frame. Is it a problem with my JSON file or import process?

Sample Data:

```
{
  "2017-11-17-blog-post-01": {
    "title": "Blog Post 01",
    "layout": "post",
    "categories": [
      "Category1",
      "Category2"
    ],
    "comments": true,
    "published": true,
    "permalink": "/blog-post-01.html",
    "basename": "2017-11-17-blog-post-01"
  },
  "2017-11-30-blog-post-02": {
    "title": "Blog Post 2",
    "layout": "post",
    "categories": [
      "Category2",
      "Category3"
    ],
    "comments": true,
    "published": true,
    "permalink": "/2017-11-30-blog-post-02.html",
    "basename": "2017-11-30-blog-post-02"
  }
}
```

Command:

```
library(jsonlite)
import <- fromJSON("test-import.json", flatten=TRUE)
```

Results:

```
$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`
$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$title
[1] "Blog Post 01"

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$layout
[1] "post"

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$categories
[1] "Category1" "Category2"

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$comments
[1] TRUE

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$published
[1] TRUE

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$permalink
[1] "/blog-post-01.html"

$`2017-11-17-blog-post-01`$basename
[1] "2017-11-17-blog-post-01"


$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`
$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$title
[1] "Blog Post 2"

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$layout
[1] "post"

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$categories
[1] "Category2" "Category3"

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$comments
[1] TRUE

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$published
[1] TRUE

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$permalink
[1] "/2017-11-30-blog-post-02.html"

$`2017-11-30-blog-post-02`$basename
[1] "2017-11-30-blog-post-02"
```

Comment: The result is 'as-expected' given the JSON format. When you say you want a `data.frame`, what are you expecting the data.frame to look like?

Comment: So, what's the issue with the JSON format? I guess I'm expect the data frame to be multiple "columns" so I can run a few processes over the data to pull out keywords and try some NLP things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(purrr)
```

Your data:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON('{
  "2017-11-17-blog-post-01": {
    "title": "Blog Post 01",
    "layout": "post",
    "categories": [
      "Category1",
      "Category2"
    ],
    "comments": true,
    "published": true,
    "permalink": "/blog-post-01.html",
    "basename": "2017-11-17-blog-post-01"
  },
  "2017-11-30-blog-post-02": {
    "title": "Blog Post 2",
    "layout": "post",
    "categories": [
      "Category2",
      "Category3"
    ],
    "comments": true,
    "published": true,
    "permalink": "/2017-11-30-blog-post-02.html",
    "basename": "2017-11-30-blog-post-02"
  }
}', flatten=TRUE) -> jsdat
```

`flatten=TRUE` works much of the time but I think `categories` is causing it to not automagically make a data frame for you, so we can give it a hand:

```
map_df(jsdat, ~{
  .x$categories <- list(.x$categories)
  .x
}, .id="id")

## # A tibble: 2 x 8
##                        id        title layout categories comments published                     permalink                basename
##                     <chr>        <chr>  <chr>     <list>    <lgl>     <lgl>                         <chr>                   <chr>
## 1 2017-11-17-blog-post-01 Blog Post 01   post  <chr [2]>     TRUE      TRUE            /blog-post-01.html 2017-11-17-blog-post-01
## 2 2017-11-30-blog-post-02  Blog Post 2   post  <chr [2]>     TRUE      TRUE /2017-11-30-blog-post-02.html 2017-11-30-blog-post-02
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. How to bring it all into a combined dataframe with these methods? Thanks

Comment: That. Is. A. Combined. Data. Frame. what abt the tibble output (fancy word for a data frame under the tidyverse) is not as expected? `categories` is a multi-element character vector. How do you want that represented if not a `list` column?